# How can I turn off ZoneAwareError in Angular?

Tags: angular, zone.js

I want to turn off [ZoneAwareError](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/zone.js/STANDARD-APIS.md#zoneawareerror) in Angular for the performance issue.

[image]
[image]

I try to find a solution at [the Documents](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/zone.js/MODULE.md), but I couldn't find it.

Are there other APIs to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have evidences that ZoneAwareError is causing performance issues? Maybe it adds few lines of code for every Error, but we are still in the case of [micro-optimization](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/micro-optimization). By the way, you can try `zone.runOutsideAngular()`

Comment: PS. In your example you're showing that the processor spends a lot of time inside a ZoneAwareError, but it doesn't say that using a plain Error it would be better! Errors (as much as Exceptions in other programming languages) are always expensive

Comment: PS. (again): Are you using Errors and try/catch inside a loop? This is a known bad practice

Comment: @CristianTraìna
I just called Promise.reject that time. When I didn't catch, Chrome show `Uncaught (in promise) [object Object]: ` Error.

Comment: @CristianTraìna And it take 0.5ms per each process.

Comment: @CristianTraìna This processor is not in angular and it called and initialized before angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by refactoring catch logic like under code.

As Is.

```
const promise = new Promise(() => {});
promise.catch(() => {});
promise.then(() => {});
```

To Be.

```
let promise = new Promise(() => {});
promise = promise.catch(() => {});
promise.then(() => {});
```